# Export content of cell based on pattern

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is part of an excel spreadsheet I have that is repeated several times:

[image]

What I want to do is find a way to copy just the "CELL TO COPY" cells to a new column. The cells that have "A" and "B" never change but the contents in "CELL TO COPY" are always different. What I thought I would do is create a new formula in column B that is `=IF(AND(A1="A",A2="B"),A4,"")` where if the first cell is "A" and the next cell is "B", it would copy the 4th cell. This formula sort of works except I do not want to have the whitespace between the cells (see output below):

[image]

Would it be possible to have a formula that does this but does not add the whitespace between, like so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following formula in B1 and copy down

```
=index($A$1:$A$100, 4*row())
```

The formula will return zero if there is no value. If you want to avoid zeroes, use:

```
=if(index($A$1:$A$100, 4*row())=0,"",index($A$1:$A$100, 4*row()))
```

Comment: It is not always every fourth row. That was just for the example. if cell A5 is "A" and A6 is "B", then it would pull cell A8

Comment: is it always after the value after ABA, or the second row after AB? What is your logic?

Comment: Either works since they will both return the same thing.

Comment: are the excluded values always B and A?